# Is $\int_{X}\omega = \int_{[X]}\omega$ for a compact manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact orientable smooth manifold of dimension n. Then we know that there exists a fundamental orientation class $[X]\in H_n(X,\mathbb{R})$.  Let $\omega$ be an n-form on $X$. Now on one hand, $\int_{X}\omega$ is well-defined, and on the other hand, $\int_{[X]}\omega$ is also defined, where the latter integral is defined by pulling back $\omega$ to a representative of $[X]$ given by a (smooth, I believe?) n-cycle.

I was wondering whether these two integrals are equal or not; also what would happen if I consider $[X]\in H_n(X,\mathbb R)$, namely considering $\mathbb R$-orientability of $X$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Defining $\int_X\omega$ you use an orientation of $X$. If that orientation is the same class as $[X]$ then they are equal, if not they are opposite.

Comment: @uldek : Does this follow from definition? I can't seem to see this from the definition; I don't know any description of $[X]$. Is there any reference for this fact?

Comment: Yes, $\int_{[X]}\omega$ is only an obfuscated way of saying how $\int_X\omega$ [is defined](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Integration_on_manifolds).